# Joomla 2.5 condition when left column empty

Tags: joomla, conditional-statements

normally I work with TYPO3. But now I got a request for a Joomla 2.5 CMS. The left column contains a submenu. But there also menu entries with only one page.

If there's no submenu I want to move content from the middle to the left.

Is it possible solving that with a condition?

regards Ingo

Answer (score 0):

In the template file you can use `if($this->countModules("position-7"){do some stuff}`. This checks if there is an active module set for the moduleposition "position-7".

This allows you to do all sort of funny things within a template. Just check the position you need and only show the whole sidebar if there is a module to show.